# Rename multiple files, removing all but one instance of a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, rename

There has to be a simple solution for my problem, but I can't get it.
I have multiple files in multiple folders, whose names have a *pattern* repeated multiple times in a row, like this:

```
20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
```

I need to remove all but one `XYZ12` of the patterns from the file names, to get the following result:

```
20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**a**) **find** + **prename**(Perl `rename`) solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*-XYZ12-XYZ12-*.gz" -exec prename 's/(-XYZ12)(\1)+/$1/g' {} \;
```

---

**b**) Additional **bash** + **find** + **sed** approach if `prename` is not supported:

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*-XYZ12-XYZ12-*.gz"); do 
    p="${f%/*}"      # full path without basename (parent folders)   
    fn="${f##*/}"    # current filename (basename)
    new_fn=$(sed 's/\(-XYZ12\)\+/-XVZ12/' <<<"$fn")  # new file name
    mv "$f" "$p/$new_fn"
done
```

---

**c**) Also, you are able to avoid using `sed` in the above bash approach by using just *bash* variable substitution:

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*-XYZ12-XYZ12-*.gz"); do 
    p="${f%/*}"      # full path without basename (parent folders)   
    fn="${f##*/}"    # current filename (basename)
    new_fn="${fn/+(-XYZ12)/-XVZ12}"  # new file name
    mv "$f" "$p/$new_fn"
done
```

Comment: I cannot try this because of `prename` , we are working with local repository only in RHEL. But thank you for your reply!

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: @Godvil, check my additional bash approach

Comment: Very simple solution, works for me. Thank you!

Comment: All the `prename` versions I could find can read file names from standard input which would allow `find ... | prename <PATTERN>`. For your use of `mv` consider that paths may start with `-` which `mv` tries to interpret as options and that the destination path may be an existing directory; GNU `mv` allows `-T --` to avoid both. For your `for ... in $(...)` loops please refer to [*Useless use of backticks*](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks). ;-)

Comment: @DavidFoerster, This is awesome article! Thank you, i will implement  `-T --` for `mv` command in the script.

Comment: (assumes files and dir names don't contain spc, tab, newline or wildcard characters (see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)) and that the directories containing those files also don't contain repeated `-XVZ12`)

Answer (score 2):

**Or you could try**:

```
find . -type f -name "*-XYZ12*" | sed 'p;s/\(-XYZ12\)\{1,\}/-XYZ12/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

See [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793892/recursively-rename-files-using-find-and-sed)

Comment: (assuming file and dir names don't contain blanks, newline or quotes or backslashes and that directories containing those files don't have repeated `-XYZ12` in their name as well.

Answer (score 2):

With `ksh93`:

```
for f in ~(N)*.log@(-+([^-]))\1*.log*; do
  echo mv -- "$f" "${f/@(*.log)@(-+([^-]))+(\2)/\1\2}"
done
```

(remove `echo` when happy).

- `~(N)`: nullglob for that pattern
- `@(...)`: grouping (so we can reference what's matched as `\1`.
- `+(...)`: one or more of the `...`.
- So `*.log@(-+([^-]))\1*.log*` is `*.log` followed by a repeated `-<non-hyphens>` followed by `*.log*`.
- `${f//pattern/replacement}`: pattern substitution operator.

So would replace: `whatever.log-repeat-repeat-repeatwhatever.log` with `whatever.log-repeatwhatever.log`.

See also [there](/a/361139) for more information on back-reference support in shell globs.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to remove all instances of `XYZ12-` first and replace the first `-` with `-XYZ12-`:

```
$ echo 20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz | sed -E 's,XYZ12-,,g' | sed 's,-,-XYZ12-,'
20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
```

**EDIT**: if you don't know `XYZ12` in advance you can extract it using `cut`. For example, create `do.sh` script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

pattern=$(echo "$1" | cut -d- -f2)

echo "$1" | sed -E "s,$pattern-,,g" | sed "s,-,-$pattern-,"
```

Usage:

```
$ ./do.sh  20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
20170223_LibError.log-XYZ12-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
```

And with another pattern:

```
$ ./do.sh  20170223_LibError.log-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-NMNM-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
20170223_LibError.log-NMNM-SAE066.log_compressed_at_2017-09-27_03-32-55.gz
```

Comment: `for file in $(ls); do echo $file | sed -E 's,XYZ12-,,g' | sed 's,-,-XYZ12-,'; done`
Can be done with your solution. Now i can store the result in `variable` and use it to rename files. Thank you!